# Design of an adder circuit

Tags: adder, carry-look-ahead

I have a adder circuit consisting of carry look ahead adders. However, I am not allowed to use the generate function to determine the sum of the two numbers. I am allowed to use basic logic operations(gates). How can I design an adder circuit under the given conditions?

Comment: As always for assignment-related questions: what have you done so far (except rephrasing the question for us)?

Comment: Do your research - a good start might be here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Microprocessor_Design/Add_and_Subtract_Blocks

Comment: Is the crux of this question... "how to design an "n" bit adder with gates"? If so, what is the relevance of the 1st line?

Comment: Wouter - Well, I tried solving the problem, but, I have not been able to progress even the slightest bit forward. So i just put the entire question up for help.
Jim - Thanks for the link. I've already studied quite a bit of what is their in the link. But even then, I am not able come up with anything.
Andy - The crux is not to design a n bit adder with gates, rather, use just the propagate function of a Carry Look Ahead adders and logical operations to arrive at the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: An adder without carry-in can be implemented with an XOR (the output value) and an AND (the output carry.)
How can you extend this to also add in the input carry?